# nHibernate Session.Load by property name

Tags: nhibernate

My DTOs have an ID that is used by my database, usually an auto-incremented INT.  My application, in general, doesn't ever care about this ID field, it tends to look up DTOs by their Name property.  Which has yielded this method in my data access layer:

```
public T GetByName(string name)
{
    return (T) Session
        .CreateCriteria(typeof (T))
        .Add(Expression.Eq("Name", name))
        .UniqueResult();
}
```

Now, what I've noticed, since this is how I load the vast majority of my DTOs, is that nHibernate isn't caching the result.  I've been able to observe, through SQL Profiler, that every call to this method results in a round-trip to the database, even if I'm certain I've loaded this particular object during my unit-of-work (an HTTP transaction).

Further, what I've read is that nHibernate will cache DTOs in a 1st level cache when you call .Load().

So, my question: is there a way to configure nHibernate to put my DTOs in the 1st level cache after being loaded in this way, or do I need to find another way to reduce my database round-trips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. Criteria will **always** go to the DB, unless you cache **the query**. You need to use `SetCacheable`, configure a cache provider and [enable query caching](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-querycache).
2. Even if you cache the query, you still need to [make the entity cacheable](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-cache-mapping) too, because NHibernate stores the object ids resulting from that query, but not the entities themselves.
3. The so-called "1st level cache" is the unit of work (session). You interact with it using the `Get` and `Load` methods, not queries. Small exception: *entities already loaded in the session* will not need to be read from the DB again.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate will not cache your entities in the first-level cache unless you load them by their primary key.

I had this same situation a while back. I never established whether entities not loaded by primary key will be cached in the second-level cache (if you're using one). Perhaps someone else can provide the answer.

Comment: What is cached in the second-level cache is determined via second-level cache configuration. In this instance, query result caching would need to be turned on since you are actually executing a query to retrieve the object.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you define the natural-id as the name field? I don't know if nHibernate will just use this just for schema generation, but it makes sense that this is the natural place to define this, regardless what nHibernate will actually do with it. If not, it's not a bad feature request.